# Pushing from Master to Development

Tags: git, gitlab

Here's the sequence:

1. Create new branch by checking out from master
2. doing my updates ..
3. Need to push those changes to development branch

- I tried to stand on development branch then merge my new branch but I face too much conflicts that resulted for difference between development & master, I need to push my changes only without resolving all the differences between development & master.
- I tried to checkout my development branch and do my changes again (copy & paste) then commit, it's working and let my branches healthy but I am seeking another approach to save duplicate work, something like merging master+my updates to development without resolving any other conflicts.

I need to keep my branch save and ready to merge with master after review by 2nd eye from my team members, so I don't need any other changes from development branch to be on my branch.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you start doing changes from `master` in the first place. Just start from the development branch.You might want to look at `git rebase --onto` though.

Comment: Why would you branch from master and merge to development?

Comment: And if you must do such a thing, what's wrong with resolving conflicts? Just resolve them. It is normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using fewer branches. One per release, or just a single branch are good approaches.

A couple of approaches:

Approach 1: Only code that is being released is pushed to Master. Between releases the team works on a single branch for the next release. When it is ready it is pushed to master. Then a new branch is created for the next release.

Approach 2: All code is pushed to trunk. Tags are used to mark releases. https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want develop to become (previous version of develop, plus your changes), then I agree with the comment above, which says to start your branch from the develop branch.

HOWEVER
You said you want to merger your feature branch to master without the changes that exist in develop.
In that case, you don't need to merge to develop.
Just have your team review your feature branch, and then merge directly to master.

EXCEPT
If you are going to want these changes on develop also, then you will either need to merge master into develop after you merge your changes into master,
OR
you can branch from develop, merge to develop, and eventually merge develop onto master.

The base problem here is that we can't provide a good answer to your question unless we know what your branching policy/strategy is.

Unfortunately, it looks like you might not have clearly defined a branching policy which say when and where and how you want features to be created and merged.